# Awk, pipe and tail -f giving unexpected behavior

Tags: linux, bash, awk, pipe, tail

Here is my sample log file.http://pastebin.com/DwWeFhJk.

When I am doing

```
tail -f log | awk '{if (NF>3) {print $1}; }'
```

the result I am getting is correct

```
64.242.88.10
64.242.88.10
64.242.88.10
64.242.88.10
64.242.88.10
64.242.88.10
64.242.88.10
64.242.88.10
64.242.88.10
64.242.88.10
```

But when I am doing:

```
tail -f log |
awk '{if (NF>3) {print $1}; }' |
awk '{print $1}'
```

I am not getting any output. Even no output in case of

```
tail -f log | awk '{if (NF>3) {print $1}; }' | grep "64"
```

I am not getting the reason why the output of the first `awk` is not getting passed as the input of the second `awk`/`grep` after the pipe.

Comment: The command `tail -f log | awk '{if (NF>3) {print $1}; }' | grep "64"` gives me the same output as you show above.  Are you sure that it is not giving you output?  If it isn't, what OS are you using?

Comment: I don't think it depends on OS. Anyways I am using arch.

Comment: awk problems do commonly depend on OS when the OS is solaris.  arch, by contrast, should be fine.  Since you mentioned that the problem occurs for `tail -f` but not for `tail`, I believe that Jonathan has identified the most likely issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the output of the first `awk` is going to the terminal, the output is line-buffered, so each line is printed as it is produced.  When the output is going to the second `awk` or the `grep`, it is fully buffered.  The output won't be sent until the buffer is full.  When enough extra records are appended to the log, then the second `awk` will a buffer full of data to process.  Until then, nothing will happen.

Comment: So, would `stbuf -oL` help here?

Comment: If you mean [`stdbuf -oL awk …`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html), then probably.

Comment: How to get the desired result in case of awk. Also why the line-buffered thing is not happening after tail -f only. I mean output of tail -f should also get line buffered and no output should be seen even in the case of tail -f log | awk '{if (NF>3) {print $1}; }

Comment: @HarshSharma: You can look up the `stdbuf` command which @John1024 mentioned, and for which I've provided a link to the documentation.  As to `tail -f`, it probably explicitly sets line buffering, whereas `awk` does not.  At least, that's a reasonable guess.  The `tail -f` will never generate an EOF (well, not until someone or something kills it with an interrupt or other signal).

Comment: A command should use interactive line buffering when detects that its input or output is being sent to a tty. If both input and output are connected to a pipe, the command may choose to do full buffering. That is why the option (in some awk versions) for interactive exists (Please take a look at my answer).

Answer (score 5):

You start the command with `tail -f`, that keeps the output open and therefore does not send a needed newline to the other commands.

This works perfectly fine:

```
cat log | awk '{if (NF>3) {print $1}; }' | grep 64
```

So, the problem is buffering. The middle awk is doing normal buffering instead of interactive buffering. This works (non-portably) with mawk:

```
tail -f log | mawk -W interactive '{if (NF>3) {print $1}; }' | awk '{print}'
```

You could read [GNU description of the issue](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Functions.html).

In any case, just check that the awk used in the middle could be told to buffer interactively.

#### Added:

The command system("") seems to unblock the buffering. It is POSIX, but does not work with mawk.

```
tail -f log | awk '{if (NF>3) {print $1}; system("")}' | awk '{print}'
```

Comment: system not working

Answer (score 2):

search for "parallel --pipe" in the link to avoid the buffering

https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html