# Festival TTS, read last line with awk filter, using tail -f

Tags: logging, awk, text-to-speech, tail, festival

I have been trying to make this work for a while now. Whenever a new line is written, I'd like festival to read this line for me. Now I am not sure how to do this. Ive tried piping festival with `tail -f` but that does not work. Does anyone have suggestions? Currently I have this code:

```
tail -f /var/log/fail2ban.log |
awk '/^[0-9.]+[.][0-9]+$/{
    if(!a[$0]++)print "Malicious IP adress " $0 " has been banned."}' RS="[ :/\n]" |
while read line; do
    echo "$line" | festival --tts
done
```

I thought of saving every last line to a new file, for festival to read every few seconds, but this takes a lot of files and is probably more complicated than needed. I do think this should be possible, but I am not sure how.

Comment: check `watch` documentation.  No need to reinvent the wheel (or watch).

Comment: This looks like yet another buffering problem. If you change the first line to `tail -f -n 10000 fail2ban.log` does it suddenly start working?

Comment: @tripleee That does not work. Its says invalid amount of rules.

Comment: @karakfa Never heard of it, then again I am quite a newb with all of this. How should I use it ?

Comment: @tripleee sorry,, yes that does run, but doesnt print new lines nor uses festival

Comment: I mean leave the rest as it is, just make sure you feed enough data into Awk to have it start spitting things out to Festival. Buffering causes the pending output to get stuck until the OS has collected enough; it does come through eventually, but you have to wait.  This is a common FAQ; if this solves your problem, your question should probably be marked as a duplicate e.g. of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33448231/awk-pipe-and-tail-f-giving-unexpected-behavior (not a stellar dupe, I can probably find a better one).

Comment: @tripleee Well after 30 minutes I got nothing out of it so It is not really helpful to keep it this way. I thank you for your time and effort, I appreciate it .

Comment: [edit] your question to tell is in what way it "does not work". Chances are you just need to add a `fflush()` after the print in your awk command though to stop awks output from being buffered.